# GitLab WebHook post-receive with WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, gitlab

I am trying to use GitLab webhook 'Push events' to notify users when there are changes in the file.

According to this [GitLab help](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/web_hooks/web_hooks.md) I should receive this as the request body:

```
{
  "object_kind": "push",
  "before": "95790bf891e76fee5e1747ab589903a6a1f80f22",
  "after": "da1560886d4f094c3e6c9ef40349f7d38b5d27d7",
  "ref": "refs/heads/master",
  "user_id": 4,
  "user_name": "John Smith",
  "user_email": "john@example.com",
  "project_id": 15,
  "repository": {
    "name": "Diaspora",
    "url": "git@example.com:mike/diasporadiaspora.git",
    "description": "",
    "homepage": "http://example.com/mike/diaspora", 
    "git_http_url":"http://example.com/mike/diaspora.git",
    "git_ssh_url":"git@example.com:mike/diaspora.git",
    "visibility_level":0
  },
  "commits": [
    {
      "id": "b6568db1bc1dcd7f8b4d5a946b0b91f9dacd7327",
      "message": "Update Catalan translation to e38cb41.",
      "timestamp": "2011-12-12T14:27:31+02:00",
      "url": "http://example.com/mike/diaspora/commit/b6568db1bc1dcd7f8b4d5a946b0b91f9dacd7327",
      "author": {
        "name": "Jordi Mallach",
        "email": "jordi@softcatala.org"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "da1560886d4f094c3e6c9ef40349f7d38b5d27d7",
      "message": "fixed readme",
      "timestamp": "2012-01-03T23:36:29+02:00",
      "url": "http://example.com/mike/diaspora/commit/da1560886d4f094c3e6c9ef40349f7d38b5d27d7",
      "author": {
        "name": "GitLab dev user",
        "email": "gitlabdev@dv6700.(none)"
      }
    }
  ],
  "total_commits_count": 4
}
```

but my WebAPI method is not resolving this request right, the things I tried are

- `public async Task Post()`
- `public void Post([FromBody] dynamic value)`
- `public void Post([FromBody] PushEvent value)` (strongly typed)

none of the above approaches seems to work, however trying this in ruby as shown in [example method](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/web_hooks/web_hooks.md#example-webhook-receiver) does work.

So I suppose this is something that have to do with the way I am using the web API. Any thoughts?

My PushEvent Class looks like this:

```
public class PushEvent
{         
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string homepage { get; set; }
    public string git_http_url { get; set; }
    public string git_ssh_url { get; set; }
    public int visibility_level { get; set; }
    public string object_kind { get; set; }
    public string before { get; set; }
    public string after { get; set; }
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public string user_name { get; set; }
    public string user_email { get; set; }
    public int project_id { get; set; }
    public IList<Commit> commits { get; set; }
    public int total_commits_count { get; set; }    

    public class Author
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }

    public class Commit
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Author author { get; set; }
    }    
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see what your PushEvent object looked like.

Comment: Also, when you say, not resolving right, what does that mean? You are getting a 404? Your breakpoint isn't getting hit? Your breakpoint is getting hit, but the object doesn't have any values, etc?

Comment: so in my situation I cannot debug this because I cannot give Gitlab webhook the localhost url, so I publish my webapi and give an URL like http:abc.com/api/hook. but I have some dummy log messages and with that I can confirm that the method is not being hit at all.

Answer (score 1):

I' ve met the same question,and my problem was caused by PAI code

the following is my code:
pushEvents:

```
namespace LuckyGitlabStatWebAPI.Models
{
public class PushEvent
{
    public string object_kind { get; set; }
    public string before { get; set; }
    public string after { get; set; }
    public string @ref { get; set; }
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public string user_name { get; set; }
    public string user_email { get; set; }
    public string user_avatar { get; set; }
    public int project_id { get; set; }
    public project project;
    public repository repository;
    public List<commits> commits;
    public int total_commits_count { get; set; }
}
public class project
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string web_url { get; set; }
    public string avatar_url { get; set; }
    public string git_ssh_url { get; set; }
    public string git_http_url { get; set; }
    public string @namespace { get; set; }
    public int visibility_level { get; set; }
    public string path_with_namespace { get; set; }
    public string default_branch { get; set; }
    public string homepage { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string ssh_url { get; set; }
    public string http_url { get; set; }
}
public class repository
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string homepage { get; set; }
    public string git_http_url { get; set; }
    public string git_ssh_url { get; set; }
    public int visibility_level { get; set; }
}
public class commits
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string added { get; set; }
    public Array modified;
    public Array removed { get; set; }
    public author author;
}
public class author
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}
 }
```

API :[how to get push info from gitlab hooks with .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40669888/how-to-get-push-info-from-gitlab-hooks-with-net/40670009?noredirect=1#comment68570529_40670009)

Answer (score 0):

I did find what the problem was, This was due to authentication. Once I allow the method  to allow anonmymous, the method was successfully hit.