# how to get push info from gitlab hooks with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, gitlab

I need  to write a website to display our team's push info. Now I meet a problem that how to get info form gitlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the type of push infomation is JSON, and what you need to do is to add a URL hook to gitlab,and the url is your API's address.
just like:
[image: pic]

and then ,click **test** button to check you API

following is my push_events API, :

```
 public int PushEventInfo([FromBody]PushEvent push)
    {
        bool flag = true;
        ProjectController project = new ProjectController();
        List<string> projectName = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = connectLocaldb.ConnectDataBase();
            conn.Open();
            string sql = "INSERT INTO MemberCommitBeforeCompiling(Username,ProjectName,Version,GroupName,CommitTime,Branch) VALUES ('" + push.user_name + "','" + push.project.name + "','" + push.after + "','" + groupname + "',getdate(),'" + push.@ref + "') ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //判断项目是否已存在
            IList<Project> namelist = project.GetAllProjectInfo();
            foreach(var i in namelist)
            {
               //如果MemberProject表中已经存在该项目
                if (i.projectName.Contains(push.project.name)|| push.project.name.Contains(i.projectName))
                    flag = false;
            }
            if (flag==true)
            {
                sql = "INSERT INTO MemberProject(ProjectName,CommitTime,isdelete) VALUES ('" + push.project.name + "',getdate(),'0') ";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\test\\log.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs); // 创建写入流
            sw.WriteLine(e.ToString()); // 写入
            sw.Close();
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: add push json info as a model class

Comment: I still don't what happened to API

Comment: when push hook was triggered, it will call your API and add json as a parameter